An example of $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \left( {C(X)}/{C_b(X)} \right) = 1$
What is an example of a Tychonoff space $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} X$ such that $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \left( {C(X)}/{C_b(X)} \right) = 1$, where we take the quotient as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces? Does there even exist such an example?
This means that there is essentially only one unbounded function on $X$ (up to scaling and addition of bounded functions). Of course, there cannot be any pseudocompact example. Essentially, this condition would mean that the space is almost pseudocompact.

Note that the restriction to Tychonoff spaces is not actually a restriction, since for any topological space $X$ we have a Tychonoff space $Y$ and a surjection $X \to Y$ inducing an isomorphism $C(X) \cong C(Y)$.


I see now that if $f \in C(X) \setminus C_b(X)$, then $f, f^2, f^3, f^4, \ldots$ are linearly independent in $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$.

There is no such example. Moreover the codimension $C_b(X)$ in $C(X)$  is at least continuum if $C(X)\neq C_b(X).$
Indeed let $h\in C(X)\setminus C_b(X).$ Then $g=|h|$ is continuous and unbounded. Thus there are $x_m\in X$ so that $g(x_m)\ge m.$ We claim that the functions $g^t(x)$ for $t>0$ are linearly independent in $C(X)/C_b(X).$ Assume for a contradiction they are linearly dependent, i.e. there are $t_1<t_2<\ldots <t_n,$ coefficients $a_1,a_2\ldots,a_{n-1}$ and $h\in C_b(X)$ such that $$g^{t_n}(x)=a_1g^{t_1}(x)+\ldots +a_{n-1}g^{t_{n-1}}(x)+h(x)$$ Thus $$1= a_1g^{t_1-t_n}(x_m)+\ldots +a_{n-1}g^{t_{n-1}-t_n}(x_m)+h(x_m)g(x_m)^{-t_n} $$ Taking the limit when $m\to \infty $ implies $1=0,$ a contradiction.

@Jakobian "The inequality $(*)$ implies that $F(x)$ is less than the non-negative root of the quadratic function $t^2-At-B,$" Could you elaborate on this?

$t^2-At-B=(t-t_1)(t-t_2)$ where $t_1<t_2.$ Thus $t^2-At-B<0$ is equivalent to $t_1<t<t_2.$ The roots $t_1,t_2$ can be calculated explicitly, but the formulas are not essential.

I should have wrote "largest" instead, the quadratic has two roots, $0$ and another non-negative one. Of course this can be zero only if $A=B=0$

Thanks, got it.

Definition 1. A subspace $X\subseteq Y$ is called $C$-embedded if every $f\in C(X)$ extends to $\tilde{f}\in C(Y)$.
Lemma 1. Let $X \subseteq Y$ be a $C$-embedded subspace. Then the minimal number of generators of $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ as a $C_b(Y)$-module is at least the minimal number of generators of $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ as a $C_b(X)$-module.
Lemma 2. Let $X \subseteq Y$ be a $C$-embedded subspace. Then
$$
\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)} \right) \geq \operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)} \right)
$$
Lemma 3. $\quotient{C(\mathbb{N})}{C_b(\mathbb{N})}$ is not countably generated as a $C_b(\mathbb{N})$-module.
Lemma 4.
$$
\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \quotient{C(\mathbb{N})}{C_b(\mathbb{N})} \right) \geq \mathfrak{c}
$$
Remark. Note that $X$ is pseudocompact if and only if $X$ doesn't contain a $C$-embedded copy of $\mathbb{N}$, for the proof see Rings of continuous functions by Gillman and Jerison.
Corollary 1. If $X$ is not pseudocompact, then $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ is not countably generated as a $C_b(X)$-module.
Remark. Corollary 1 cannot be improved to show that if $X$ is not pseudocompact then any generating set of $C(X)/C_b(X)$ as $C_b(X)$-module must be of size $\geq \mathfrak{c}$. For explanation see this answer of mine.
Corollary 2. If $X$ is not pseudocompact, then
$$
\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)} \right) \geq \mathfrak{c}
$$
Proof of Lemma 1: Let $A \subseteq C(Y)$ be a set of minimal cardinality with the property that its projection to $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ is a generating set for $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ as a $C_b(Y)$-module. Let $A|_X \subseteq C(X)$ be the collection of all restrictions $f|_X$ for $f \in A$. Take any $g \in C(X)$. Since $X$ is $C$-embedded in $Y$, we can extend it to some $\tilde{g} \in C(Y)$. Since the projection of $A$ to $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ is a generating set for $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ as a $C_b(Y)$-module, we can write
$$
\tilde{g} = h_1 f_1 + \ldots +h_n f_n + i
$$
for $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in A$, $h_1, \ldots, h_n \in C_b(Y)$ and $i \in C_b(Y)$. Hence we have
$$
g = h_1|_X f_1|_X + \ldots +h_n|_X f_n|_X + i|_X
$$
This shows that $g$ lies in the $C_b(X)$-submodule of $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ generated by the projection of $A|_X$ to $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$. Since $g$ was arbitrary, we see that the projection of $A|_X$ to $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ is a generating set for $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ as a $C_b(X)$-module.
Hence the minimal number of generators of $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ as a $C_b(X)$-module is at most the minimal number of generators of $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ as a $C_b(Y)$-module. $\square$
Proof of Lemma 2: Let $A \subseteq C(Y)$ be a set with the property that its projection to $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ is a basis for $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Let $A|_X \subseteq C(X)$ be the collection of all restrictions $f|_X$ for $f \in A$. Take any $g \in C(X)$. Since $X$ is $C$-embedded in $Y$, we can extend it to some $\tilde{g} \in C(Y)$. Since the projection of $A$ to $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ is a basis for $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, we can write
$$
\tilde{g} = t_1 f_1 + \ldots +t_n f_n + h
$$
for $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in A$, $t_1, \ldots, t_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h \in C_b(Y)$. Hence we have
$$
g = t_1 f_1|_X + \ldots +t_n f_n|_X + h|_X
$$
This shows that $g$ lies in the subspace of $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ generated by the projection of $A|_X$ to $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$. Since $g$ was arbitrary, we see that the projection of $A|_X$ to $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ is a generating set for $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.
Hence the dimension of $\quotient{C(X)}{C_b(X)}$ is at most the dimension of $\quotient{C(Y)}{C_b(Y)}$. $\square$
Proof of Lemma 3: Striving for a contradiction, assume that $\quotient{C(\mathbb{N})}{C_b(\mathbb{N})}$ is countably generated as a $C_b(\mathbb{N})$-module by $f_1, f_2, f_3, \dots$. Via a diagonal-like argument, define
$$
F(n) = f_1(n)^2 + \ldots + f_n(n)^2
$$
Now we can write
$$
F = \sum_{k = 1}^N g_k f_k + h
$$
for some $g_1, \ldots, g_N \in C_b(\mathbb{N})$ and $h \in C_b(\mathbb{N})$. Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we obtain
$$
0 \leq F(n) \leq \sum_{k = 1}^N a_k \cdot |f_k(n)| + B \leq A \cdot F(n)^{\frac{1}{2}} + B
$$
with $a_k = \|g_k\|_\infty$, $A = \left( \sum_{k = 1}^N {a_k}^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $B = \|h\|_\infty$ for $n \geq N$.
Hence we have
$$
\left( F(n)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right)^2 - A \cdot F(n)^{\frac{1}{2}} - B \leq 0
$$
for all $n \geq N$. However, the set on which the quadratic function $t^2 - A t - B$ is $\leq 0$ is bounded, showing that $\sup_{n\geq N} F(n)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty$, and hence $F$ must be bounded, a contradiction.
This contradiction shows that $\quotient{C(\mathbb{N})}{C_b(\mathbb{N})}$ is not countably generated as a $C_b(\mathbb{N})$-module. $\square$
Proof of Lemma 4: Take some bijection $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$. For some irrational number $x$, we can consider the continuous function $f_x: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}, f_x(n) = \frac{1}{|g(n) - x|}$. Set $A = \{f_x \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\} \subseteq C(\mathbb{N})$. We will show that the projection of $A$ to $\quotient{C(\mathbb{N})}{C_b(\mathbb{N})}$ is linearly independent. Assume that
$$
a_1 f_{x_1} + \ldots a_n f_{x_n} = g
$$
with $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $g \in C_b(\mathbb{N})$. Take some $1 \leq i \leq n$ and a sequence $(q_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ with $q_m \to x_i$ as $m \to \infty$. Set $k_m = g^{-1}(q_m)$. Then $f_{x_j}(k_m) = \frac{1}{|q_m - x_j|} \to \frac{1}{|x_i - x_j|}$ for $i \neq j$ and $f_{x_i}(k_m) = \frac{1}{|q_m - x_j|} \to \infty$. Since $a_1 f_{x_1} + \ldots a_n f_{x_n}$ is a bounded function on $\mathbb{N}$, this implies $a_i = 0$. Since $1 \leq i \leq n$ was arbitrary, this implies that $a_1, \ldots, a_n = 0$.
Hence the projection of $A$ to $\quotient{C(\mathbb{N})}{C_b(\mathbb{N})}$ is linearly independent. Additionally, the cardinality of the projection of $A$ to $\quotient{C(\mathbb{N})}{C_b(\mathbb{N})}$ is $\mathfrak{c}$. Hence $\quotient{C(\mathbb{N})}{C_b(\mathbb{N})}$ has a linearly independent set of size $\mathfrak{c}$, implying that it has dimension at least $\mathfrak{c}$. $\square$
